# Can we use "the more" in comparative sentence?

Tags: grammar

When I was solving English tests, I came across this question.

Of the two athletes, Ronald has been ..... in winning cups than Kane

a) more successful    b) successful
c) the more successful  d) the most successful

Undoubtedly, my choice was A(more successful). Because it is a well-known rule in comparative sentences. But I wonder when I saw an answer. The answer was C (the more successful). Can anybody explain to me the reason for this? Can we use the more with the comparative sentence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in what cases we should use "the more" instead of "more"?

Comment: I'm sorry; the correct version is (a) here, not (c). Without the 'than X', either ' ... more [successful in winning cups]' or '... the more ...' is fine. Using 'the more' is arguably better standalone ('Of the two athletes, Ronald has been the more successful'). It's more formal where there's a choice.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. It would be Ronaldo, not Ronald.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, I got it

Comment: You are right@iMb. A) is indeed the correct choice. See my answer for the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

All of these work:

- Of the two athletes, Ronald has been more successful than Kane.
- Of the two, Ronald has been a more successful athlete than Kane.
- Of the two athletes, Ronald has been the more successful [one].
- Of the two, Ronald has been the more successful athlete.

In this structure, “the more” seems to function as a superlative (like “the most” if there were three or more), which can’t be followed by “than”, whereas “more” and “a more” are normal comparatives like you’d expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Of the two athletes, Ronald has been **{more successful}** in winning cups than Kane. - More is an adverb modifying the adjective "successful"

Of the two athletes, Ronald has been **{the more successful}** in winning cups than Kane - **successful** is an adjective acting as a noun = successful person/sportsman

"The first round will eliminate 50% of the contestants. The successful *(uncountable = those who are successful)* will progress to round two."

Comment: How can I decide when to use more and when the more in such tests? I mean are there any rules when to use the more and when without the?

Comment: The guidance is: (i) **the** + more + **noun** (**the** modifies 'noun'); (ii) **more** + **adjective** (there is no noun.)

Comment: Don't use _the more_. It's just a slightly more formal and more precise usage, referring here to the original definite NP _the two athletes_ by echoing _the_.

Comment: There are only a few cases when "the more" is usable and they all relate to a comparison between two people or things. For instance you could say "of the two pictures the Van Gough is the more valuable" but you would have to say "of the collection of 50 pictures the Van Gough is the _most_ valuable"

Comment: @BoldBen Thank you. Your explanation is very clear

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you, I got it

Comment: "The" as a modifier of "more" is excluded if the secondary term is expressed, as it is here ("than Kane").

Answer (score 0):

> *Of the two athletes, Ronald has been ..... in winning cups than Kane*.

I agree with you, iMb.

I don't know why the answer says that c) *the more successful* is correct, since "the" is excluded if the secondary term is expressed, as it is in your example, i.e. *than Kane*.

b) *successful* is not possible because the comparative term "more" is required, and d) contains *most* which is not a possible comparative governor.

That leaves only a) *more successful*, which would be my choice.